# Using discord.js, how can I slice unnecessary parts of an API result off to send?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

The API in question is a pun one, namely this one. The code I am using is as follows:

```
const superagent = require("superagent")
module.exports = { 
    run: async(client, message, args) => { 
    const pun = await superagent.get("https://getpuns.herokuapp.com/api/random")
    message.channel.send(pun.text); 
    }, 
aliases: [] 
}
```

The API returns `{"Pun":"I'm going to stand outside, so if anyone asks I'm outstanding."}`. This is as expected, but I'd like to be able to remove some parts for it to end up as `I'm going to stand outside, so if anyone asks I'm outstanding`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `pun.text` holds the value `{"Pun":"I'm going to stand outside, so if anyone asks I'm outstanding."}`

You can try replacing `pun.text` width `pun.text.Pun` .

Comment: ah yeah, that makes a lot of sense. I previously tried it with just pun.text.pun and was wondering why it didn’t work. just realised my mistake, thanks!